# Print not giving any output

Tags: python, mcmc

I wrote a code to perform some Metropolis-Hastings MCMC and when I ask for it to print a list of results, nothing happens not even an error message. Does anyone know why I'm not getting any output?

```
def Gaussian(sigma, x, mu):
    p = 1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))
    return p

N = 10
i = 0
x[0] = 0.5
results = []

for i in range (0,N):
    y = x[i] + np.random.normal(0,0.01)
    H = Gaussian(1,y,1)/Gaussian(1,x[i],1)
    alpha = np.random.uniform(1,1)
    if H >= alpha:
        x[i+1]=y
        results.append(y)

print(results)
```

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2):

You can not initiate a python list as **x[0] = 0.5**

if you want to hardcore x[0] = 0.5 then use it as x=[0.5]

hope this works for you

Comment: That worked! But now it is giving me an error that the list index assignment is out of range for the step in the if statement where I set x[i+1]=y

Comment: Yes, for sure it gives you this error, because the length of your list named x is one but you are try to read the value of index 1 which  does not exist. make a loop here eg. for i in range(0,N): and append the values in this list. like x.append(your values)

Comment: Awesome thank you! One last problem. It works part of the time and gives me the list I want but then other times if I run it again it tells me list index is out of range for the y = x[i]+np.random.normal(0,0.01). Why would it sometimes work and other times not?

Comment: import numpy as np
def Gaussian(sigma, x, mu):
    p = 1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))
    return p

N = 10
x=[]
for i in range(0,N):
    x.append(0.5)
results = []

for i in range (0,N):
    y = x[i] + np.random.normal(0,0.01)
    H = Gaussian(1,y,1)/Gaussian(1,x[i],1)
    alpha = np.random.uniform(1,1)
    # print x[i]
    if H >= alpha:
        x.append(y)
        results.append(y)

print(results)        

Read this code snippet, will work for you